# SHOW connection_id()

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I can inspect the current Connection ID by using:

```
SELECT connection_id();
```

And it returns the id:

```
# connection_id()
'6558851'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.processlist 
WHERE id = connection_id();

# ID, USER, HOST, DB, COMMAND, TIME, STATE, INFO
'6558851', 'abc', '99-51-01-something:55353', 'XA', 'Query', '0', 'executing', 'select * from information_schema.processlist plist where id=connection_id()'
```

Where is that function (if it's a function?) defined though? I've checked in `sys` and `information_schema` and was unable to find a function defined with that name. Where is this located then?

---

Update, on reviewing this a bit more, it seems like these are just [built-in functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html) to the mysql database -- i.e., no different than using a `GROUP_CONCAT()` or any other function, for example:

```
SELECT connection_id(), now(), id, email FROM auth_user limit 10;
```

In this way it would be defined in the C++ code rather than as a user/system-defined function. Is that a correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CONNECTION_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) is a built-in function compiled in MySQL and therefore it is not contained in a database.

So yes, your understanding is correct.

To avoid confusion, I want to specify that:

- [User-defined functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html) (UDFs), are also not stored in a database. They are installed globally by the user.
- [Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) created by the used in SQL are stored in a database.

Comment: thanks! btw, this is so cool! https://github.com/federico-razzoli/sql_games/tree/master/anagram

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to contribute by adding words in English or any other language you know :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a thread _id which you see in `SHOW Prpcesslist`

> ID

> The connection identifier. This is the same value displayed in the Id column of the SHOW PROCESSLIST statement, displayed in the PROCESSLIST_ID column of the Performance Schema threads table, and returned by the CONNECTION_ID() function within the thread.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-processlist-table.html